# Bar Chart, Caption & Sources

Tags: bar-chart

Right now, i am working on a Bar Chart and i wanna put a caption and sources below the bar chart. However, the code, \begin{figure}, caption{XXX} and \end{figure} are not working at all. Other than that, i also want to remove  the line in the cell of the left bottom corner and then put 4 lines into it so that they are easier to read. Any ideas would be so helpful. Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{\hfill Source: {#1}} }
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{caption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
% read in data
\pgfplotstableread{
x v nv nvv nvvv nvvvv
1989/90 3.1 0.1 2.2 17.2 77.4
1990/91 2.7 0.1 2.2 17.1 78.0
1991/92 2.0 0.1 2.3 17.1 78.6
1992/93 1.9 0.2 2.3 17.3 78.4
1993/94 3.2 0.3 2.3 17.5 76.6
1994/95 2.3 0.8 3.1 17.8 76.0
1995/96 2.0 1.9 5.1 17.8 73.2
1996/97 1.5 0.9 5.8 18.7 73.1
1997/98 1.8 1.1 6.4 18.9 71.8
1998/99 1.5 1.5 7.2 19.6 70.3
1999/00 1.3 0.7 7.9 19.1 71.0
2000/01 0.8 0.1 8.4 18.2 71.6
2001/02 1.1 0.8 9.2 18.2 70.8
2002/03 1.2 0.9 10.3 18.1 69.5
2003/04 1.1 1.2 10.5 17.4 69.7
2004/05 1.0 1.0 10.6 16.5 71.0
2005/06 1.6 1.0 10.9 15.9 70.5
2006/07 3.0 0.8 11.5 15.6 69.1
2007/08 3.4 0.9 11.8 15.4 68.5
2008/09 2.8 0.9 12.8 15.1 68.4
2009/10 1.8 1.1 13.7 14.9 68.5
2010/11 2.3 1.1 13.9 14.5 68.2
2011/12 2.5 1.3 14.5 14.3 67.4
2012/13 2.3 1.7 13.9 13.9 68.2
2013/14 2.2 1.1 14.3 13.6 68.7
}\datatable

% get number of rows
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
% subtract 1 because table indices start at 0
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Nrows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
% for convenience, macro to store width of axis
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\MyAxisW}{25cm}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  cell/.style={ % style used for "table" cells
    draw,
    minimum width={\MyAxisW/(\Nrows+1)}, % +1 because -1 above
    minimum height=4ex,
    inner sep=0pt,
    outer sep=0pt,
    anchor=north west,
    font=\sffamily\scriptsize
  }]
\begin{axis}[
   name=ax,
   title= Mix of Financing Sources of Private Health Expenditure (at current market prices) 1989/90-2013/14,
   % so axis labels and ticklabels are not accounted for in size settings   
   scale only axis,
   width=\MyAxisW,
   height=4cm,
   % use a stacked bar char
   ybar stacked,
   % we add the ticklabels as part of the table, so no xticks needed
   xtick=\empty,
   % set distance between yticks
   ytick distance=10,
   % and add grid lines
   grid=major,
   % only need left y-axis line
   axis y line=left,
   x axis line style={draw=none},
   % divide axis width by twice the number of rows, so that the whitespace between
   % bars is the same as the bar width ...
   bar width={\MyAxisW/(2*\Nrows+2)},
   % and for that we need to make sure that the distance from the first/last tick
   % to the axis edge is the same, so that there is a half a bar width of space
   enlarge x limits={abs={\MyAxisW/(2*\Nrows+2)}},
   ymin=0,
   ylabel={Share(\%)},
   xlabel={},
   % move xlabel to below table
   xlabel shift=30ex,
   % set yticks as sans serif
   tick label style={
    font=\sansmath\sffamily\small,
    % and remove comma in 1,000
    /pgf/number format/set thousands separator=},
   % set axis labels as sans serif
   label style={font=\sansmath\sffamily}
  ]
  % because the x-values are not evenly spaced, used index as x-value instead
  \addplot +[purple!90] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=nvvvv] {\datatable};
  \label{dataNVVVV}

  \addplot +[blue!30] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=nvvv] {\datatable};
  \label{dataNVVV}

  \addplot +[yellow!60] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=nvv] {\datatable};
  \label{dataNVV}

  \addplot +[green] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=nv] {\datatable};
  \label{dataNV}

  \addplot +[orange] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=v] {\datatable};
  \label{dataV}
\end{axis}

% define a starter coordinate at the lower left corner of the axis
\coordinate (c-0-0) at (ax.south west);

% loop over the table
\foreach [count=\j from 1] \i in {0,...,\Nrows}
  {
  % get element \i from the x-column, stored in \pgfplotsretval
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{x}\of\datatable
  % add node with value
  \node [cell] (c-0-\j) at (c-0-\i.north east) {\pgfplotsretval};
  % repeat for other two columns
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{v}\of\datatable
  \node [cell] (c-1-\j) at (c-0-\j.south west) {\pgfplotsretval};
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{nv}\of\datatable
  \node [cell] (c-2-\j) at (c-1-\j.south west) {\pgfplotsretval};
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{nvv}\of\datatable
  \node [cell] (c-3-\j) at (c-2-\j.south west) {\pgfplotsretval};
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{nvvv}\of\datatable
  \node [cell] (c-4-\j) at (c-3-\j.south west) {\pgfplotsretval};
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{nvvvv}\of\datatable
  \node [cell] (c-5-\j) at (c-4-\j.south west) {\pgfplotsretval};
  }

% add "legend" on the left
\matrix [draw,nodes={cell,draw=none},anchor=north east,row sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,inner ysep=0pt] (m) at (c-1-1.north west)
{
 \node {\ref{dataV}};  & \node{Others}; \\
 \node {\ref{dataNV}}; & \node{Non-profit institutions}; \\
 \node {\ref{dataNVV}}; & \node{Insurance}; \\
 \node {\ref{dataNVVV}}; & \node{Employers}; \\
 \node {\ref{dataNVVVV}}; & \node{Households}; \\
};

% draw center line of legend
\draw (m.west) -- (m.east);
\end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When you are saying that "\begin{figure}, caption{XXX} and \end{figure} " do not work at all, did you compile the document in the `standalone` class or a class that supports the figure environment?

Comment: yes i did. just didn't know why i couldn't put a caption and sources.

Comment: You can use \capionof{figure}{...} with standalone.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter - I'm not sure exactly where he wanted the caption.  Also, you need to use varwidth or a minipage.  In any case, it is not a good idea.